# How to create a symlink so that modifications are transfered to the orignal file?

Tags: symlink

I never created a symlink but I installed bitcoin core and I need to put the blockchain on a different hard drive (let's call it **A**) than the wallet (on hdd **B**). So my idea is to create a symlink of the whole blockchain directory into the config directory of bitcoin core (which is on B). However I am worried that this will not work as I am not sure whether bitcoin core will download subsequent new blocks on A or on B. Can you confirm that bitcoin core will keep downloading new blocks on A where the blockchain folder is ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether Bitcoin plays ball with symlinks or not, I can't confirm. But symlinks do function the way you're intending them to, ie B will update once A does because, really, it's just a shortcut.